# how to use socket in node.js in order to response client and admin explicitly and separately using an html file?

Tags: android, node.js, sockets, web, socket.io

I have written an API for client side in node and I want that when a client hits the end-point only a string response is shown to client but as client hits the API an html file should be updated on the client side. Please let me know how to generate separate responses to client and admin from a single API in node.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.sendfile('index.html');//sending file in response to client
});
// something like above  is been done which sends response file to the client but i wants that it only updated and shown to the admin at the time of request.

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
         //socket imported
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
       //end-point 'ring'
app.post('/ring', (request, response)=> 
{
    console.log(request.body); 
    const data=request.body;

    if(!data)
    {
        //if data is not sent then error status
        return  response.status(400).send('bad request');
    }
    // here i need to implement explicit responses
        console.log((`data is----> ${data}`));
    //here i'm emitting my json object to the html file
    // this json object should be sent to the html to show
    io.emit('message'{'requestbody':request.body,'status':'ringing'});
    // sending success response to the client
    response.status(200).send('ringing');
});
```

Index.html code

```
<body>
    <script src=”/socket.io/socket.io.js”></script>

    <script 
    //initializing socket
        var socket = io();
    //trying to recieve json object from socket
        socket.on(‘message’, addMessages)>//calling the addMessage function
    </script>

    <script>
        function addMessages(message)
        {
        //setting the text extracted from json object
           $(“#messages”).append(`
        //setting probeId  
              <h4> ${message.probeId} </h4>
        //setting status
              <p>  ${message.status} </p>`)
        }
    </script>

  //my 'index.html' file should be updated when user hits the ring api and user gets a string response.
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you don't need socket for what you need.
If my understanding of the question is good enough, you can just add a parameter to separate  the type of return

```
app.post('/ring', (request, response)=> 
        {
            console.log(request.body); 
            const data=request.body;

            if(!data)
            {
                //if data is not sent then error status
              return  response.status(400).send('bad request');
            }
            if(data.returnType === 'html'){
                response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
            } else {
                response.status(200).send('ringing');
            }
})
```

returnType is a POST parameter to separate the return types.

## update :

if you want to update your index

```
app.post('/ring', (request, response)=> 
        {
            console.log(request.body); 
            const data=request.body;

            if(!data)
            {
                //if data is not sent then error status
              return  response.status(400).send('bad request');
            }
            if(data.returnType === 'html'){
                response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
            } if(data.returnType === 'json'){
              // Business logic here
              let result = { a: 'aez' };
              return response.json(result);
            } else {
                response.status(200).send('ringing');
            }
})
```

## And in your html

```
<body>
   <script>
       $("#envoyer").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
                 url : 'send_mail.php',
                 type : 'POST',
                 data : 'dataType=json'
                 success: handle
               });

     });

     function handle(result, status)
      {
        //setting the text extracted from json object
        $(“#result”).append(`<div> ${result.a} </div>`)
      }
     </script>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but actually our data is of type json and we do not want to send index .html in client response at all ,what we want is to update an admin page whenever this api hits..so any suggestions?

Comment: i updated the question to show how you can do it using jquery ajax